# Best practices for creating searchable field to be used in Solr

Tags: solr

Would it be considered a good practice to merge multiple searchable fields into 1 large searchable field and lower/upper case it for performance benefits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as merging multiple fields into one field, yes, that would be quite reasonable.  If it supports your searching needs, it's a good idea.  Using [`copyField`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields) in your schema xml makes this easy.  A reasonably common example, is creating a field merging all fields into one big searchable grab-bag:

```
<copyField source="*" dest="text"/>
```

There really isn't any particular need to lowercase before analysis.  Most analyers (including `StandardAnalyzer`) will take care of that for you.